# IIS 7.0 rewrite module for file name

Tags: regex, iis, mod-rewrite, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a website with many links to *.index.html pages that do not exist any more, all default documents have now changed to index.htm, I'm trying to set a URL redirect/rewrite to the new pages but with no luck, here is an exmaple:

```
http://example.com/somedirectory/maybeanotherdirectory/index.html
```

I need to redirect that request to:

```
http://example.com/somedirectory/maybeanotherdirectory/index.htm
```

I have added different rules to the web.config but so far I can only redirect to:

```
http://example.com/index.htm
```

How do I sustain the exact path while only changing index.html to index.htm?

Comment: If I had an IIS server up and running, I'd try to figure it out again and help you out, but I remember that trying to write those rules was pretty confusing... of course, I also only used it through the GUI before, so maybe I wouldn't be helpful anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such an old question, and I stumbled across it purely by happenstance. In case anybody comes across it in look for an answer, you can install the [IIS URL ReWrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module, and add the following to your web.config:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Html to htm">
                <match url="(.*)\.html" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.htm" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Cheers!